# How do I use WinHttpRequest and SetTimeouts with small values?

Tags: c#, winhttprequest

I'm trying to perform a web request using AHK that will time out after 1 second. This script will be called after a certain key combination.

For my smartphone I have a small HTML app that does the call using AJAX and times out properly after 1 second.

This is the AHK script:

```ahk
SendCode(code) {
  HttpObj := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

  try {
    HttpObj.Open("GET","http://192.168.1.120/?" + code)
    HttpObj.SetTimeouts(1000,1000,1000,1000)
    HttpObj.Send()
  } catch e {
    MsgBox, Error executing code: %code%
  }

  ObjRelease(HttpObj)
}

SendCode(24)
SendCode(26)
```

Since I'm more proficient with C# I also tried it with a .NET console application:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string url = "http://192.168.1.121/?24";
    const int timeout = 1000;

    double stopWatch;

    dynamic HttpObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1"));

    HttpObj.Open("GET", url);
    HttpObj.SetTimeouts(timeout, timeout, timeout, timeout);

    stopWatch = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
    try
    {

        HttpObj.Send();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    stopWatch = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds - stopWatch;
    Console.WriteLine(stopWatch);
    Console.Read();
}
```

This outputs

```
  4029,00729998946
```

When I don't specify SetTimeouts the timeout occurs after 30 seconds. Is there anyway to do this using WinHttpRequest?

Using the .NET WebClient class I can also set a timeout of 1s without problems.

Thanks